# Undefined reference to static library methods inside another static library

Tags: c++, static-libraries, linker-errors, zlib, libzip

After failing to install a C++ libzip wrapper named libzippp because of a broken Cmake, I decided to compile/link it myself as it's tiny enough.

Problem is that this lib has two dependencies, `zlib` and `libzip`.  So I Cmaked those two and proceeded into making the .a using MinGW (win32).  I then linked my library to my program and then compiled it, no errors.

Code below:

```
//lib creation command lines  

    g++ -c libzippp.cpp -o libzippp.o -std=c++11 -lzlib -lzip
    ar rcs libzippp.a libzippp.o

//Programm compilation (simplified)

    $(CC) -o $(EXEC) $(OBJ) $(CLFLAG) -lzip -lzlib -lzippp
```

After that I tried executing basic libzippp methods but here began the errors as the linker calls out for undefined reference.

**The undefined reference comes from inside the lib, they're undefined references to the "Libzip" dependency**

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/.././..
  /libzippp.a(libzippp.o):libzippp.cpp:(.text+0x236e): 
                                        undefined reference to `_imp__zip_fclose'
```

But if I simply compile my program using libzippp as a simple compile unit I'm able to use the lib without any linker errors.

Example below :

```
//Compilation works, lib works

    $(CC) -o $(EXEC) $(OBJ) libzippp.h libzippp.cpp $(CLFLAG) -lzip -lzlib
```

As a I'm not a very experienced programmer I've assumed that I just failed the creation of the lib.  It's the first time I've make a lib that needs other libs to work and I believe my error come from here.

Comment: `CLFLAG` is a very non-standard name for compilation flags. Better use separate `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`. Also you do not need to specify libs when compiling `libzippp.o`.

Comment: I just didn't wrote my LDFLAGS var as it only contained the tree libs and I wanted it as lisible as possible, and I just forgot the S at the end of CLFLAG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move `-lzippp` before `-lzip`, otherwise linker will not link files from libzip:

```
$(CC) -o $(EXEC) $(OBJ) $(CLFLAG) -lzippp -lzip -lzlib
```

That's how static libs work.